# Android battery mucking up

Tags: battery, charging

I have an unusual problem with my galaxy s4 battery.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Sometimes when the battery level is 85% it can shut off and when I turn it back on it can go straight to 0%. Also sometimes the battery level seems to be able to rise even when i am using it and its not being charged.

I ran a virus scan using AVG and found no viruses. Please help me find fix this problem.